# Nginx redirect with parts of URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a redirect problem with nginx and I really don't know how to do it.

The problem is that I need to redirect all the traffic to a website **INCLUDING THE PATH**

**BASE_URL**: https://example.com/auth/

For example if the request is: https://example.com/auth **/some/path/**

I need it to redirect to: https://newdomain.com **/some/path/**

In other words, I need to concatenate the part of / some / path / to the new URL.

Here is the part of my code that I have tried

```
   location  /auth/* {
          proxy_pass https://newdomain.com/$request_uri; 
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the issue seems to be the URL handling. You need a small regexp and get the result.

try:

```
  location  ~ ^/auth/(.*)$  {
      proxy_pass https://newdomain.com/$1; 
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```

You can find examples there https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/